# Is this expression calculated multiple times?

Tags: c, for-loop

```
int a = 100;
int b = 10000;
int c = 22;
int i;

for (i = 0; i < a + b; i++)
{
    c++;
}

#define MAX_GROUP_A_NUM 5000
#define MAX_GROUP_B_NUM 10000
#define MAX_GROUP_NUM (MAX_GROUP_A_NUM + MAX_GROUP_B_NUM)

for (i = 0; i < MAX_GROUP_NUM; i++)
{
    c++;
}
```

1. Is a + b calculated multiple times in the first loop?
2. Is 5000 + 10000 calculated multiple times in the second loop?

Thanks in advance.

According to the information searched on the Internet, it is depends on factors such as compiler implementation and compilation options. Is this true?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/as_if

Comment: Yes, it depends on the compiler and options, but most compilers at any non-zero optimization level will compile those loops into an addition of a constant.

Comment: `MAX_GROUP_A_NUM = MAX_GROUP_B_NUM` Shouldn't that be: `MAX_GROUP_A_NUM + MAX_GROUP_B_NUM` (i.e. `+` instead of `=`) ?

Comment: According to this answer, some compilers might optimize comparing against a constant even when no optimizations are enabled: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24848563/2527795

Comment: Quote "Is this true?" Yes, it's true. The C standard doesn't specify how things are to be done. The standard only specifies the observable result. So one compiler may generate instructions that include add of `a` and `b` in every loop iteration. Another compiler may do the add a single time before the loop. A third compiler may remove the whole loop and just do a single assignment to `c`. The only way to find out is to look at the assembly generated by the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

Since the inputs are all constants, most compilers won't produce a loop at all. For example, I modified your code as follows so it would compile:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = 100;
    int b = 10000;
    int c = 22;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < a + b; i++)
    {
        c++;
    }

    #define MAX_GROUP_A_NUM 5000
    #define MAX_GROUP_B_NUM 10000
    #define MAX_GROUP_NUM (MAX_GROUP_A_NUM + MAX_GROUP_B_NUM)

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_GROUP_NUM; i++)
    {
        c++;
    }
}
```

What the compiler produced was:

```
main:
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

This is basically just `int main { return 0; }`, with no loop or anything else--we didn't use the values produced, so the compiler figure out it was all dead code and eliminated it.

Okay, so let's print out each value after we produce it, so it can't do that. When we do that, we get:

```c
        .string "%d\n"
main:
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     esi, 10122
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        xor     eax, eax
        call    printf
        mov     esi, 25122
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        xor     eax, eax
        call    printf
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
```

This is basically equivalent to:

```c
int main() { 
    printf("%d\n", 10122);
    printf("%d\n", 25122);
    return 0;
}
```

So, the compiler has "realized" that all inputs are fixed constants, so the output of each is also a fixed constant. So, it does all the actual computation at compile time, and just generates code to print out the two constants (the 10122 and 25122). Still probably not quite what we wanted, but starts to hint at the sort of optimization a compiler can do.

So let's make its life a little more difficult. Instead of everything being fixed constants, we'll read values for `a` and `b` from the command line, then do our loop:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int a = atoi(argv[1]);
    int b = atoi(argv[2]);
    int c = 22;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < a + b; i++)
    {
        c++;
    }

    printf("%d\n", c);
}
```

Here's what that produces:

```c
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     edx, 10
        push    rbx
        mov     rbx, rsi
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     rdi, QWORD PTR [rsi+8]
        xor     esi, esi
        call    strtol                   
        mov     rdi, QWORD PTR [rbx+16]
        xor     esi, esi
        mov     edx, 10
        mov     rbp, rax
        call    strtol
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        add     eax, ebp
        test    eax, eax
        lea     esi, [rax+22]
        mov     eax, 22
        cmovle  esi, eax
        xor     eax, eax
        call    printf
        add     rsp, 8
        xor     eax, eax
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

I don't know whether you read assembly language, but I do and I can tell you: that code doesn't contain any loop at all. It's not just hoisting the computation of `a+b` out of the loop--it's eliminating the loop completely. It's basically seeing that the final value of `c` is `a + b + 22`, so it's just computing that directly, and printing it out.

That's code from gcc. Clang produces slightly different code, but only slightly different--the generated code still doesn't contain a loop.

I used `-O3` with both--there's no point in paying attention to what code a compiler produces when you turn off optimization.

That, of course, is only two compilers--but I'd expect most others to do similar optimization. As I recall, I routinely got similar results from Microsoft C 6.0 in the 1980's, so this isn't something new and extremely sophisticated, or anything like that.

#### Summary

The generated code doesn't contain a loop at all, so there's no multiple evaluation of anything.

Answer (score 1):

In the first scenario, it depends on the compiler's optimizer. However, this is a very easy optimization to do so even bad compilers ought to pre-calculate it, given that optimizations are enabled.

In the second scenario, `MAX_GROUP_A_NUM + MAX_GROUP_B_NUM` is a compile-time constant, what the C standard calls *integer constant expression*. Since the C standard says that such expressions may be used at compile time, for example when stating the size of the array, the compiler has no other option but to calculate it at compile time, no matter optimization level. So it gets replaced with `15000`.

Putting either code inside a function and testing it with gcc or clang (x86) and optimizations enabled `-O3`, both snippets result in the whole code including the loop getting optimized away and replaced by `return 10122` and `return 15000` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

**General answer**

The C standard generally specifies the observable result of running a given piece of code. This allows for automatic optimizations as long as the observable result is unchanged, but there is no requirement that such optimizations must be done.

So in short: Yes, it is true that this depends on the compiler and compilation options.

**Analyzing compiler behavior**

Thus to determine which optimization is done in a specific case, it is necessary to look at the generated machine language.

The weakness of constructed examples as in the OP is that compiler optimizers are getting so good that they will likely conclude that the result is a constant and optimize the entire code into that constant.

Thus, to analyze the for loops, it is necessary to declare the variable `c` as `volatile` which tells the compiler that it cannot optimize away access to that variable.

**Example without optimization**

In [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/1xaa4PbY4), the result of building the OP code with the mentioned modification without optimization with GCC 13.2 for x86-64 is seen.

In the first loop, `a+b` is calculated for each iteration.

In the second loop, 5000+10000 is calculated is compile time. The loop is generated by having a counter going from 0 to 14999, exactly as the loop variable `i` in the code.

**Example with optimization**

In [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/5d15boh6T), optimization is enabled (`-O1`, but increasing the optimization level does not change the result significantly).

Here, variables `a` and `b` are optimized away and replaced by a single constant with their sum `10100`. Hence, `a+b` is calculated only once (at compile time).

Likewise, 5000+10000, is calculated at compile time. In this case the loop control is optimized compared to the previous example by having a counter going from 15000 to 1 and terminating the loop as the counter is decreased to 0 after the last iteration. This is done because comparing to 0 is a specialized function in the machine language which is more efficient than comparing with 14999 and it can be done because it does not change the observable result when running the code.

Answer (score 0):

The code:

```
for (i = 0; i < a + b; i++)
{
    c++;
}
```

as written it requires the calculation of the expression `a + b` every time the loop test is executed.  But, a good optimizing compiler can see (and a good programmer) that the expression will not chenge inside the loop, and so, substitute it by an equivalent:

```
const temp = a + b;
for (i = 0; i < temp; i++)
{
    c++;
}
```

or even (not requiring the variable at all, just the value)

```
for (i = 0; i < 15000; i++)
{
    c++;
}
```

With respect to the code:

```
#define MAX_GROUP_A_NUM 5000
#define MAX_GROUP_B_NUM 10000
#define MAX_GROUP_NUM (MAX_GROUP_A_NUM + MAX_GROUP_B_NUM)

for (i = 0; i < MAX_GROUP_NUM; i++)
{
    c++;
}
```

After the C preprocessor has run, it gives to the compiler the following equivalent code:

```
for (i = 0; i < (5000 + 10000); i++)
{
    c++;
}
```

in which you are computing if `i < 15000` (the compiler will evaluate a constant expression and will substitute the value instead) resulting in:

```
for (i = 0; i < 15000; i++)
{
    c++;
}
```

probably, assuming the compiler still obeys the `register` storage modifier (which is not the case) would transform the code into the following:

```
register const temp = a + b;
for (i = 0; i < temp; i++)
{
    c++;
}
```

which will probably save machine cycles shortening the loading and caching the loop limit into a cpu register.

An aggressive compiler can even change the whole loop into (I've seen this):

```
i = 15000;
c += 15000;
```

and after seeing the next loop would have eliminated the assignment to `i`, as the value assigned to it is never used again.  You will see this if you run the compiler on this code:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 0xffffffffU; i++)
    continue;
```

and optimize for speed. You will see how fast can a computer count up to 4 billion times. :)