# How do I turn this runtime-efficient function into a constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++11, fibonacci, constexpr

I'm using C++ `constexpr` to evaluate, at compile time, the largest term of the calculated Fibonacci sequence that this code can correctly evaluate.  To do this, I use this code:

```
constexpr unsigned long long fibo(unsigned n) {
    return (n < 2) ? 1 : fibo(n-1)+fibo(n-2);
}

constexpr unsigned max_fibo(unsigned n) {
    return (fibo(n+1) >= fibo(n)) ? max_fibo(n+1) : n;
}

const unsigned MAX_FIBO_TERM = max_fibo(0);
```

This works just fine and quickly constructs the correct value for `MAX_FIBO_TERM` (92 on my machine).  However, using that `fibo` function to actually calculate terms at runtime is extremely slow (it takes almost 90 seconds to calculate only the first 48 terms).

I can use an alternative function to calculate the terms which is much faster:

```
unsigned long long fiboiter(unsigned n, unsigned long long &prev, 
                            unsigned long long &prevprev) {
    return prev = (n < 2) ? prevprev = 1 : 
        (std::swap(prev, prevprev), prev + prevprev);
}
```

However, I can't seem to make this into a valid `constexpr` function.  (This is why it's written in that strange way.)  When I run this version, it takes 0.005 seconds on my machine.

When I compile with `g++ -O2 -std=c++11 fibo.cpp -o fibo` it only takes 0.302 seconds.

My question is: **How can I use the same efficient function both at runtime and compile time?**

I'm using g++ 4.8.3 on a 64-bit Linux machine, but what I would like is a cross-platform universal answer rather than simply one specific to this compiler and machine.  And no, C++14 is not yet an option in this situation.

Also, my question is similar to, but not the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24708114/how-can-the-compile-time-be-exponentially-faster-than-run-time) because I'm asking about how to use the same runtime-efficent code at compile time and not why or how the compile-time code is made efficient.

Here's the full program.

### fibo.cpp

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

constexpr unsigned long long fibo(unsigned n) {
    return (n < 2) ? 1 : fibo(n-1)+fibo(n-2);
}   
unsigned long long fiboiter(unsigned n, unsigned long long &prev, 
                            unsigned long long &prevprev) {
    return prev = (n < 2) ? prevprev = 1 : 
        (std::swap(prev, prevprev), prev + prevprev);
}    
constexpr unsigned max_fibo(unsigned n) {
    return (fibo(n+1) >= fibo(n)) ? max_fibo(n+1) : n;
}    
const unsigned MAX_FIBO_TERM = max_fibo(0);

int main(int argc, char **)
{
    // format numeric output according to user's preferred locale
    std::cout.imbue(std::locale{""});
    unsigned long long prev, prevprev;

    if (argc > 1) {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i <= MAX_FIBO_TERM; ++i) 
            std::cout << "fib(" << std::setw(2) << i << ") = " 
                      << std::setw(26) << fiboiter(i, prev, prevprev) << '\n';
    } else {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i <= MAX_FIBO_TERM; ++i) 
            std::cout << "fib(" << std::setw(2) << i << ") = " 
                      << std::setw(26) << fibo(i) << '\n';
    }
}
```

### Sample output

```
fib( 0) =                          1
fib( 1) =                          1
fib( 2) =                          2
fib( 3) =                          3
fib( 4) =                          5
fib( 5) =                          8
 ...
fib(89) =  2,880,067,194,370,816,120
fib(90) =  4,660,046,610,375,530,309
fib(91) =  7,540,113,804,746,346,429
fib(92) = 12,200,160,415,121,876,738
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Good compilers optimize tail recursion well, try a tail-recursive `constexpr` implementation:

```
constexpr unsigned long long fibo(unsigned n,
                                  unsigned long long prev = 1,
                                  unsigned long long prevprev = 0) {
    return n == 0 ? prev : fibo(n - 1, prev + prevprev, prev);
}
```

[According to the clang on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e275393a1bebf2a), both `constexpr` and non-`constexpr` versions take 5-6 milliseconds to complete (and that's probably I/O dominated).

Answer (score 1):

```
template<size_t max, class F, size_t...is, class R=std::result_of_t<F(unsigned)>>
R memoize(std::index_sequence<is...>,unsigned val){
  static R cache[]={ F{}(is)...};
  if (val<max)return cache[val];
  return F{}(val);
}
template<size_t max, class F, class R=std::result_of_t<F(unsigned)>>
R memoize(unsigned val){
  return memoize<max,F>( std::make_index_sequence<max>{}, val );
}
struct fib_t{
  constexpr auto operator()(unsigned val)const{
    return fibo(val);
  }
  constexpr fib_t() {}
};
```

then `memoize<100, fib_t>(x)` will be fast at runtime up to 100.

A faster `fibo` will make it faster post 100.

While `index_sequence` is C++14, here is a replacement that should work for up to a few 100 elements:

```
template<std::size_t...>struct indexes{using type=indexes;};
template<std::size_t M, std::size_t...Is>struct make_indexes_t:make_indexes_t<M-1,M-1,Is...>{};
template<std::size_t...Is>struct make_indexes_t<0,Is...>:indexes<Is...>{};
template<std::size_t M>using make_indexes=typename make_indexes_t<M>::type;
```

and replace `std::make_index_sequence` with `make_indexes`, and `std::index_sequence` with `indexes`.

If you need answers past a few 100, you'll need a more robust `make_indexes` than the above.  There are many implementations in the wild, they mainly consist of divide-and-conquer (write concatenate, and write a make_indexes that goes from min to max via recursively splitting the range and concatenating.  This gives logarithmic template recursion depth).

`std::result_of_t` is C++14, but `template<class Sig>using result_of_t=typename std::result_of<Sig>::type` is a drop-in replacement.

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting, but aren't `result_of` and `index_sequence` C++14 constructs?

Comment: @edward `result_of` is C++11.  `index_sequence` is C++14, but easy to generate a "good enough" implemention in C++11.  [Here](http://loungecpp.wikidot.com/tips-and-tricks%3aindices) are [two](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/39648/improved-indices-trick) (with slightly different names for the types, as they predate C++14).  The first one is simple and "good enough", the second is required if you have on the order of 1000 indexes to reduce template recursion depth.  I'll add a simple one to the answer above.

Comment: @edward typo fixed, and `result_of_t` implementation added.